# Perform INSERT INTO ... SELECT in AWS GLUE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

The following script populates a target table with the data fetched from a source table using `pyspark.sql` and runs without problems in AWS Glue:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

users = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="source", table_name="source_users"
)

users.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("users")
query_users = """
SELECT U.id
      , signup_from
FROM users AS U
"""

users_df = spark.sql(query_users)
users_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
    users_df.repartition(1), glueContext, "users_dynamicframe"
)
users_output = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=users_dynamicframe,
    database="target",
    table_name="target_users",
    transformation_ctx="users_output",
)

job.commit()
```

Now, I would like to perform an `INSERT INTO SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`
and I wrote the following script:

```
source_users = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="source", table_name="source_users"
)

target_users = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "target", table_name = "target_users"
)

source_users.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("source_users")
target_users.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("target_users")


query = """
INSERT INTO target_users
SELECT U.id
       , U.user_type
FROM source_users 
on duplicate key update id=target_users.id
"""

target_output = spark.sql(query)
job.commit()
```

which returns the following

`ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'on' expecting <EOF>`

I am not sure how to achieve this, and the reason why I am trying this is to reflect in the target table the updates happening in the source table.
Any help in this direction would be massively appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: spark sql is not supporting the update.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus, so how can I run the glue job ensuring that updates in the source table are reflected into the target one?

Comment: load both table and join, overwrite.